Object not aligning to the artboard its on - Illustrator CC
I have had an ongoing issue for a while now of occasionally if I am trying to align something to an artboard it will align to another artboard. Sometimes this happens sometimes it works so its difficult for me to pinpoint what is going on. I select the artboard using the artboard tool but even still sometimes it will align to another artboard.

Your selected object will align to whichever artboard is highlighted in the Artboard Pallet (Window> Artboards).
If you have an object selected and then click an artboard with the Artboard Tool to select that artboard the object will align to that artboard.
If you do not have an object selected and then click to select an artboard with the Artboard Tool and then select an object the highlighted artboard will change to the artboard the object is on.
You can see this if you open the Artboard Pallet and watch as you select objects and/ or artboards. The Artboard Pallet gives you a clear indication of where any aligning actions will take place.
EDIT— If you move something from artbaord 1 to artboard 4 and leave it selected it will align to artboard 1 (which will still be  highlighted in the Artboard Pallet). You either need to highlight artboard 4 in the Artboard pallet or select off the object and re-select it as this will associate the newly moved object with artboard 4.
